# How to quit the QEMU monitor when not using a GUI?

Tags: qemu

I'm running QEMU on Linux without GUI.

After running starting my custom kernel with QEMU, I can't kill and return to host by pressing Ctrl+C.

Is there any way to get back to host OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.

1. Opened new terminal session: ctrl+alt+f2
2. Used ps to find PID of previous tty: ps -fu
3. Killed previous tty: kill -HUP PID

Comment: This is a really inferior solution to the most upvoted answer here. I will not downvote the answer, since it was entered before the better solutions.

Comment: Not necessarily inferior, it still caters to situations where the CtrlA,X way doesn't work, eg when qemu gets stuck trying to bring up an OS. It's just an alternate answer.

Answer (score 144):

**`Ctrl-A X`**

For `-nographic` just enter:

```
Ctrl-A X
```

which means

1. first press <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> (A is just key <kbd>a</kbd>, not the <kbd>alt</kbd> key),
2. then release the keys,
3. afterwards press <kbd>X</kbd>.

Alternatively:

- enter the QEMU monitor with `Ctrl-A C` then type:

  ```
  quit
  ```

  and press enter. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165158/how-to-switch-to-qemu-monitor-console-when-running-with-curses
- use the QEMU monitor (same as `Ctrl-A C`) with `telnet`:

  ```
  qemu-system-x86_64 -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -serial mon:stdio
  ```

  and on a host terminal:

  ```
  telnet localhost 45454
  ```

  and then `quit` from there.

  `-serial mon:stdio` is required to keep Ctrl+C working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to/49751144#49751144
- shut down the VM from guest normally, e.g. with a `powerdown` command from a Linux guest shell if you are able. This of course goes through the normal shutdown sequence instead of immediately killing the VM, but sometimes it is just the simplest approach.

  It does not work for all machines however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990487/how-to-cleanly-exit-qemu-after-executing-bare-metal-program-without-user-interve

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10, QEMU 2.10.1.

Comment: The example in the other answer is clearer

"ctrl+a, then x"

Comment: @vharron yes, my amazing explanation skills have finally been surpassed

Comment: The telnet trick worked for me, as my qemu was being started on a port.

Comment: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/mux-chardev.html

Answer (score 15):

To close a QEMU process in your shell:

`ctrl+a`, then `x`

Comment: When using -nographics and -monitor need to include -serial mon:stdio que keep ctrl+a working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to/49751144#49751144

Answer (score 9):

Press `Cntl-Alt-2` and then use the close button on the menu.

[image]

You can find more useful shortcuts [here](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/qemu_guide.html)

Comment: I found the `Ctrl` part unnecessary. `Alt-2` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

This is just in addition to other answers, where `ctrl-a x` works but you've aliased over it. If you're like me, you're using tmux with `ctrl-b` replaced with `ctrl-a`, which is why you can't use `ctrl-a x`. A simple solution to this is to use tmux's `send-keys` utility to send `ctrl-a x` to qemu.

In a running tmux window, press `ctrl-a :` to bring up the tmux prompt, then type `send-keys C-a x Enter` and qemu will quit.